# How to read Java files with contain many splits

Tags: java, filereader

```
BB [FL:60 BT:10 SG:20 MK:10 | 12]
```

I have above data on a text file and I need to get integer values separately

In brief first BB represent food type
 with ":" split represents materials 
and with "|" represent time to make it

How can i get those 5 parameters in java using File reader Thank you

Comment: You should first show your code that you have attempted to do this task. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to show how to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex matcher here, and iterate over your input string, matching pure numbers as you go along:

```
String input = "BB [FL:60 BT:10 SG:20 MK:10 | 12]";
String regex = "\\d+(?=[^0-9.])";
List<Integer> vals = new ArrayList<>();

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

while (m.find()) {
    vals.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group(0)));
}

for (int val : vals) {
    System.out.println("Found an integer: " + val);
}

Found an integer: 60
Found an integer: 10
Found an integer: 20
Found an integer: 10
Found an integer: 12
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Split, split, trim & split:

```
-> String code = "BB [FL:60 BT:10 SG:20 MK:10 | 12]"
|  Added variable code of type String with initial value "BB [FL:60 BT:10 SG:20 MK:10 | 12]"

-> String[] mattime = code.split ("[\\]\\[\\|]");
|  Modified variable mattime of type String[] with initial value [Ljava.lang.String;@2286778
|    Update overwrote variable mattime

-> mattime [1]
|  Expression value is: "FL:60 BT:10 SG:20 MK:10 "
|    assigned to temporary variable $32 of type String

-> String[] elem = mattime [1].split (" ")
|  Modified variable elem of type String[] with initial value [Ljava.lang.String;@13a5fe33
|    Update overwrote variable elem

-> for (String e: elem) println (e);
FL:60
BT:10
SG:20
MK:10

-> for (String e: elem) {println (e); String [] kv = e.trim().split (":") ; println (kv[0] + " : " + Integer.parseInt (kv[1])); }
FL:60
FL : 60
BT:10
BT : 10
SG:20
SG : 20
MK:10
MK : 10
```